# 1 up-to-date issue with VisualStudio 2010 and Visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to generate an .exe using visual studio 2010, for the first it builds fine but if i delete the .exe and again if try to build without making any changes in file for the second time, its not generating the .exe again and it is just showing as follows even if the .exe is not present,

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

On searching the internet, i found it may be possible to build again, by everytime using "rebuild" option of VS2010. But i dont want to use rebuild option as i am generating .exe via command prompt always using something like devenv /build "Debug|x64".....

I also Tried to build using Visual Studio 2012 and still facing the same problem for 2nd time generation.

Please suggest me with a solution. I am trying from two weeks and found no solution(except "rebuild" option) which works fine with this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error building in VS2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18848492/error-building-in-vs2012)

Answer (score 1):

Project Properties -> Build Events -> Post-Build Events -> Command Line:

```
del /F /Q "$(IntDir)\$(MSBuildProjectName).lastbuildstate"
```

This will delete lastbuildstate file after every build, so .exe file will be regenerated every time.

Comment: Firstly, i dont want to delete everytime manually *.lastbuildstate file generated, Is there any solution to disable the generation of *.lastbuildstate file. Secondly, i've a query that is disabling *.lastbuildstate file works fine? If so please suggest me the way to disable *lastbuildstate file.

Comment: As I know there's no way to disable it's generation.

Comment: I searched in internet and found something like to disable fast uptodate check using, <PropertyGroup>  
  <DisableFastUpToDateCheck>true</DisableFastUpToDateCheck>
</PropertyGroup>    . Is this a correct solution for this issue.

Comment: Please Suggest me with a solution .I am trying from one month and found no solution.

Comment: Hi Ivan Ishchenko,                                                    It is not working del /F /Q "$(IntDir)\$(MSBuildProjectName).lastbuildstate"                       Please suggest me solution.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the name of the project in the Solution Explorer window and then "Rebuild"